# jQuery PHP session_destroy

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am trying to call a php script which destroys session and reload a page after it.

```
$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
  $.post("data.php?data=active");
  location.reload();
});
```

data.php

```
if($_GET['data'] == 'active') {
  session_destroy();
}
```

It does not destroy the session, only if I manually open the url data.php?data=active it does, why is that? Thanks!

Comment: is there session_start() in your data.php?

Comment: I think you need to initialize the session with session_start() prior to destroying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the script you send the request to is using its own session. So, the user has a session, which is different from the session you send the "refresh idle state" request.

One solution would be to just start a timer using javascript and when that timer runs out, just refresh the page.

That's why it only works when you actually access the data.php page.

Comment: To be honest i don't quite get this answer: Why should the script you send the request to use it's own session? Both share the same session cookies and thus use the same session. And even if: How would a timer help?

Comment: Because the browser (i.e. the user loading the page) is a different "client" to the server, than the script which sends a request.

Comment: Where did he mention, that he sends the request from another script? As i read it, the request is initiated from some javascript from the browser. So i'd assume it's the same session cookie.

Comment: He didn't have to mention, that's how a server works. Your browser, and the actual page (which resides on yet another server) are two different clients, each with its own session.

Comment: I meant "two different clients for the server"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data stored in the `$_SESSION` array, you need to start or resume the existing session using `session_start()`. In your data.php, try this:

```
if($_GET['data'] == 'active') {
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
}
```

Please, take in consideration that `session_start()` should be used **before** you send any output to the client.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Modified:

```
$.post("data.php", {data: active}, function(whatever){}
```

and in your php file use:

```
$_POST['data'];
```

Comment: That's not true. Even for `POST` requests, URL parameters can be read from `$_GET`.

Comment: in the php file, you need to grab the $_POST once you send it via ajax / jquery

Comment: he is using a querystring ?data=active as the data so $_GET works just fine

Comment: i suppose so, except i like to pair my ajax request in both the send (via post) and the grab (via post) just so there is no confusion

Comment: Good sir, you do realize your answer is wrong, right? Why do you persist with useless edits and additional details, that are also wrong?